# c# harmony example not print injection logs as expected

Tags: c#, aop

the C# harmony documentation: https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/wiki/Prioritiy-annotations
my question is that not able to run the C# harmony example successfully

the postfix annotation didn't get injection log printed as expected after Class and method get patched that i didn't see "injection logs"  get printed.

c# code example below. Can someone help me find the issue
you may paste into https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to debug it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Harmony;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var harmony = HarmonyInstance.Create("net.example.plugin");
        harmony.PatchAll(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Bar();
    }

    [HarmonyPostfix]
    [HarmonyPatch(typeof(Program), "Bar")]
    public static void Postfix_Bar(){ 
        Console.WriteLine("postfix Bar log");  // this never gets printed as expected. 
    }

    [HarmonyPostfix]
    [HarmonyPatch(typeof(Program), "Foo")]
    public static void Postfix_Foo(ref string res){  //however, this gets error res could not be found.  https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/wiki/Prioritiy-annotations
        Console.WriteLine("postfix Foo log");
        res = "new value";
    }

    public void Bar() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World !!! ");
    }

    static string Foo()
    {
        return "secret";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `PatchAll()` looks for classes that have at least on `[HarmonyPatch]` annotation. Your patches are in the class `Program` which does not have that annotations. This is the main problem in your example.

Solution: either annotate your Program class like this:

```cs
[HarmonyPatch]
public class Program
{
}
```

or create a new class that has that annotation.

The second problem I can see is that `Postfix_Foo(ref string res)` uses `res` which does not follow the documented standard for naming patch arguments. It can either be the name of an argument that the original method has (it has no arguments) or refer to the result, which requires it to be named `__result`.

The comment about priority annotations is misplaced too because they only apply to multiple patches to the same original method.

Finally, you call `Bar()` after patching which means that `Foo` is never called - not sure if that’s intended.